# Dynamic Programming Problem "Total rating must be highest after buying players with input price"

Tags: java, data-structures, knapsack-problem

[Players Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWfcs.png) The problem is making total rating maximum , while buying one player from each position with some price. For example 29000€. You can use 27000€ but you can't use 29001€.

Note: You can only buy one player from each positions so if there are 6 positions and each position has 10 players , count of all possibilities is 11^6

All i can see is knapsack problem but i think there should be some great solution for this problem.

I already tried knapsack algorithm but it didn't work well for bigger inputs like 11 positions and each position have 50 players to check.

```java
int DP()
{
   int price = 29000;
   int positions = 3;   // I tried this approach , it is unfinished though. 
   int players = 3;

   int ratings[][] = new int[positions][players];
   int prices[][] = new int[positions][prices];
   int K[][][] = new int[positions][price][players];

   for(int i = 0; i <= positions; i++)  
  {
      for(int j = 0; j<=players; j++)
        {
           for(int w = 0; w<=price; w++)
                {
                   if(i==0||j==0||w==0)   // Base case.
                       K[i][j][w]=0;
                   else if(prices[i-1][w-1] <=w)
                       K[i][j][w] = max(ratings[i-1][j-1] + K[i-1][j-1][w-price[i-1][j-1]], K[i-1][j-1][w];
                   else
                       K[i][j][w] = K[i-1][j-1][w];
                }
        }
  }
    return K[positions][players][price];
}
```

Example Output:

```
Enter the amount to spend (X): 100 000
Enter the number of the positions (N): 6 //The first N position
Enter the number of the available players for each position (K): 5
// The first K players of each position
DP results:
Total ratings : 547
Total cost: 98 925
Players:
1-Gianfranco Zola
2-Jimmy Floyd Hasselbaink
3-...
4-...
```

Answer (score -1):

I find an implementation for this knapsack problem, try to run this with your scenario.
this will help you!!

```
/**

 ** Java Program to Implement Knapsack Algorithm

 **/



import java.util.Scanner;



/** Class Knapsack **/

public class Knapsack

{

    public void solve(int[] wt, int[] val, int W, int N)

    {

        int NEGATIVE_INFINITY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int[][] m = new int[N + 1][W + 1];

        int[][] sol = new int[N + 1][W + 1];



        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)

        {

            for (int j = 0; j <= W; j++)

            {

                int m1 = m[i - 1][j];

                int m2 = NEGATIVE_INFINITY; 

                if (j >= wt[i])

                    m2 = m[i - 1][j - wt[i]] + val[i];

                /** select max of m1, m2 **/

                m[i][j] = Math.max(m1, m2);

                sol[i][j] = m2 > m1 ? 1 : 0;

            }

        }        

        /** make list of what all items to finally select **/

        int[] selected = new int[N + 1];

        for (int n = N, w = W; n > 0; n--)

        {

            if (sol[n][w] != 0)

            {

                selected[n] = 1;

                w = w - wt[n];

            }

            else

                selected[n] = 0;

        }

        /** Print finally selected items **/

        System.out.println("\nItems selected : ");

        for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++)

            if (selected[i] == 1)

                System.out.print(i +" ");

        System.out.println();

    }

    /** Main function **/

    public static void main (String[] args) 

    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Knapsack Algorithm Test\n");

        /** Make an object of Knapsack class **/

        Knapsack ks = new Knapsack();



        System.out.println("Enter number of elements ");

        int n = scan.nextInt();



        int[] wt = new int[n + 1];

        int[] val = new int[n + 1];



        System.out.println("\nEnter weight for "+ n +" elements");

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)

            wt[i] = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter value for "+ n +" elements");

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)

            val[i] = scan.nextInt();



        System.out.println("\nEnter knapsack weight ");

        int W = scan.nextInt();



        ks.solve(wt, val, W, n);

    }

}
```

Comment: I voted +1 for you but why does it look "-1" ? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: But this solution is for one dimensional knapsack , i mean i try to choose the best from  " values[position][player] " 2D array , so it becomes double dimensional problem :/

Comment: this is '-1' because you accidentally clicked downvote button may be

Comment: I guess I'm newcomer so my votes can't be seen. Maybe we should use knapsack for each possible group then get maximum of them but it still looks like it'll take long.